# PC vs mobile browser - same width columns using percentages - Mobile is inaccurate

Tags: html, css, math, mobile, multiple-columns

So, what I'm doing is trying to lay out some columns that are of equal width using percentages for responsive design.  The way I'm going about doing it is calculating the percentages of each column (accounting for right margins, too) and having the final column take up the remaining width, all while getting a total of 100%.

Example:  3 columns, 30% wide
Columns 1 and 2 would have a width of 30% and margin-right of 5%.
Column 3 would just be 30% with no margin.

**Math:** 30 + 5 + 30 + 5 + 30 = 100%

To get this result, I'm doing the following:

### HTML

```
<div class="columns" id="exmpl1">
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col_last"> <span class="buffer">3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.col {
    float: left;
}
.col_last {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#exmpl1 .col {
    background-color: #205CDC;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#exmpl1 .col_last {
    background-color: #D02020;
}
.buffer {
    padding: 40% 0;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with more: https://jsfiddle.net/0kwbabjz/1/

Now, some might ask why not set the final column to the same width?  Some browsers (typically older) seem to calculate incorrectly and the final column winds up going to the next line.  This method ensures that the last one just takes up whatever space remains.  Plus, with uneven columns it's more handy to just do it that way.

Now, the problem is with mobile browsers.  I don't know if they can't do simple math or what, but I have found this method almost always makes the final column appear BIGGER than the rest.  I tested my Fiddle above and the 5 column example's final column does indeed appear bigger.  This is a big problem when trying to display a gallery of images where equal size is the goal.

Is this a limitation of mobile browsers, can they not do precise math, or is there something else that can be done?  Internet Explorer 7 can do this math with no problems, as can all PC browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: well try to use width:30% instead of 19 then  you will see there is no difference. I thought it depends on margin too which you are giving to two column but not to last one..still diggin more..

Answer (score 0):

Just make the width 30%. It will make the all of 3 columns 30% wide.

width = 30*3 = 90%

margin: 5%+5% = 10%

Total : 100%

```
#exmpl3 .col {
    background-color: #0FE;
    width: 30%; /*make the width 30% */
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```css
.col {
    float: left;
}
.col_last {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#exmpl1 .col {
    background-color: #205CDC;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#exmpl1 .col_last {
    background-color: #D02020;
}
#exmpl2 .col {
    background-color: #DC5C20;
    width: 19%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
}
#exmpl2 .col_last {
    background-color: #20D020;
}
#exmpl3 .col {
    background-color: #0FE;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#exmpl3 .col_last {
    background-color: #206000;
}
.buffer {
    padding: 40% 0;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #400094;
    background-color: #DBAB00;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
strong{
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2>EXAMPLE 1 - CORRECT MATH</h2>

<div class="columns" id="exmpl1">
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">2</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col_last"> <span class="buffer">3</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="columns" id="exmpl2">
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">2</span></div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">3</span></div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col_last"> <span class="buffer">5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<p>Math of 30 + 5 + 30 + 5 + remaining (which is 30) equals 100 percent. <br />
    Math of (19 + 1.25) * 4 + one more 19 = 100% too.<br />
    Math is done correctly.  In this example, the final column appears OK on the PC, but <strong>bigger</strong> on mobile browsers...</p>

<h2>EXAMPLE 2 - EMULATING MOBILE BROWSERS</h2>

<div class="columns" id="exmpl3">
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col"> <span class="buffer">2</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col_last"> <span class="buffer">3</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well rahul kumar, he did not ask how to achive the structure but the reason why in mobile layout 3rd column is different. Please read question back with time.Thanx

Comment: Hi.  I know that would work in some browsers, but I'm trying to not have to do that for the final column.  Just have width: auto and overflow: hidden to force it to take up the remaining space.

I guess I may have to just calculate manually at this rate.  :(